# Thymeleaf change variable

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am new in Thymeleaf and i need to do something like this:

```html
<div th:each="element : ${list}" th:with="test=false">
    <div th:each="element2 : ${list2}">
        <div th:if="element2.name == 'someName'">
            <div th:with="test=true">test changed</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:text="${test}"></div>
</div>
```

If i try this code i see "test changed" but my variable test is always false

Answer (score 1):

A with expression creates or overrides a **local variable**.

That means that the modified variable is only accessible inside the element you declared the with expression on.

In your case the output of test is written outside of the modification div so you get the result from outside.

Comment: Thank You for answer, can You tell me is it possible to change value of local variable? If yes how, if no what is the best solution to create something similar what i need?

Comment: You can change it but only use the changed version inside this dom element where you declared the with expression. What do you want to achieve? Most likely there is another way than using with.

Comment: I have List<User> with place and position. I have to view something like this: Place1(Position1(user1, user2)), Position2(user3, user4)), Place2(Position1(user5)) etc. Before i create div with position i need to check if any position and place of user belong to correct view, if no i dont create div. I just need to change my variable like in example.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask that question either here or in the thymeleaf forum. How to render.... You also have the th:if attribute to decide if a tag should be rendered. You create a method on place for example "hasposition" and you use it in the th:if.

Comment: Has an answer been provided for this question? I am trying to achieve something similar to what Dawid K was facing - Use th:with while iterating over a loop to 0, and re-assign it back to 0 on a certain condition.