# Thymeleaf: re-assign a local variable

Tags: spring, variables, thymeleaf

I've a code like this:

```
<div th:each="element : ${list}" th:with="test=false">
    <div th:each="element2 : ${list2}">
        <div th:if="element2.name == 'someName'">
            <div th:with="test=true">test changed</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:text="${test}"></div>
</div>
```

but the variable "test" is always is always false. What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf change variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597604/thymeleaf-change-variable)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable defined in `th:with` is available only within the bounds of the containing `<div>` tag. This is explained in the Using Thymeleaf Guide, Local Variables [section](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables).

There is no way to update the local variable globally using `th:with`.

Comment: I know... Is there another way (without th:with) to reach the same result?

Comment: I think there is no way using Thymeleaf only, to achieve something like this maybe could be using javascript or using a model attribute defined, check: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Simple-Counter-with-defined-variable-td4026976.html